# QNX SDK available for MAC

Tags: qnx

Is there any QNX SDK available for MAC? I had found one for Windows and for Linux.. But Can't find one for MAC... Would be so helpful if anyone help me in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to say "no, I've never seen a Mac package for QNX", but a simple Google search reveals that if you are trying to target BlackBerry, they have something.

See [this link](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.native_sdk.quickstart/topic/after_the_install.html).

If you're not targeting BlackBerry, then you should probably give their [QNX-hosted development VM](http://www.qnx.com/download/group.html?programid=20905) a try. This should work pretty well on any modern host machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ya my target is for BB. So am gonna try this one from the link which you've shared. QNX-hosted development VM is the one which am using using right now.

Answer (score 2):

For those targeting the QNX Neutrino RTOS:

I just found a very nice gem inside the [Momentics IDE for Blackberry](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/downloads/) installed on a Mac. Simply go to **File->Preferences** and in the side-bar select **QNX->Profiles** and check the box **QNX Developer**.

You now have access to the QNX project wizards and can target the Neutrino RTOS. I'm developing everything on my Mac with Momentics and a QNX Neutrino target running on a VMWare virtual machine (supplied  by QNX). I can connect to the VM target with `qconn` and going through the [first steps tutorial](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0SP1/momentics/quickstart/about.html) was a breeze.

**My current setup:**

- Yosemite 10.10.5
- Momentics IDE for Blackberry IDE 2.1.2
- VMware Fusion 8
- QNX-supplied VMware image of Neutrino RTOS 6.5.0 SP1 runtime

Comment: I think this solution only works for targeting QNX binaries for x86. .I am in same boat but need to crosscompile for ARMv5 32bit LE

Comment: I was running into issues and ended up just using a virtual machine with VMware fusion and Momentics SDP on Debian. QNX supplies an image of Neutrino that works with VMware for software development.